# Bevel a 2x6 long ways

Tags: wood

apologies if this question is answered.

I need to make a bevel plate (of 10 degrees) to support wooden I-joists on a single slope (shed) roof assembly. I'm working with 2x6s, and I'd really like to cut the ten degree bevel across the 5.5'' dimension of the board, but I am really struggling to figure out how to do it.

Just to be clear, I need to rip these 2x6 long ways, with a 10 degree bevel going the width of the board to support a wooden I-joist at 10 degree angle.

I thought I could cut the boards on both sides with a circular saw, but unless I have a monster (8'' + inches) circular saw they blade is too short for the cut to meet in the middle.

Any ideas?

Comment: The bevels only need to be at the joist bearing points.  Why not cut a series of shims tapering at 10 degrees to be placed under each joist at the bearing point?

Comment: It is typical to make a "birds-mouth" for angled members that need to rest on support members like this. Maybe show a sketch so we can be sure we know what you are talking about?

Comment: Assuming you don't go another route..... *"unless I have a monster (8'' + inches) circular saw they blade is too short for the cut to meet in the middle"* easy peasy, IF you can do those initial cuts with the circular saw safely, just saw the little tab/fillet of wood that remains using a hand saw, then clean up as needed. Many table-saw resawing operations on very wide boards are done in this way.

Comment: This was a duplicate question cross-posted to woodworking and migrated here. It's now a _true_ duplicate here. The other one has _more_ answers, though none accepted there, either.

Answer (score 3):

I voted to close this since it's really a construction question and belongs in the DIY site, but the best way to do this is going to be shimming up one side and running the board through a planer.

Basically you'll draw your angle on the endgrain, get a piece of MDF wider and longer than your work piece, then use framing shims to get your line parallel to the sheet of MDF.  Tack/screw the shims in place and then tack stops on all the sides of the board to keep it from moving on the MDF.  Make sure none of your brad nails/screws will contact the planer blades (or poke through the MDF to hit the planer bed).  Then run it through till you hit your line.